# PowerShell: Variable loses its value in userform

Tags: powershell

I have a script with a userform with which you can edit an ad user object.

The script runs fine directly on our server but when I try to run it from my system with admin privileges, `New-PSSession` and a few `Invoke-Command`'s the necessary variables are losing their values.

Here's my code (Some stuff has been censored):

```
#--------------------#
# Function GUI > GUI #
#--------------------#
Function GUI
{
    #---Param
    [String]$BadgeListCSV = "link" # -> Badge list

    [Bool]$UserChk        = $False                                                             # -> Indicates if the user has been found

    [Bool]$BadgeChk       = $False                                                             # -> Indicates if the badge is already linked with an ad object

    [Int]$BadgeIndex      = 1                                                                  # -> Badge Nr.

    #Global variables
    Set-Variable -Name Exit -Value $True -Scope Global

    #---Importing badge list
    Try
    {
        $BadgeList = Import-CSV $BadgeListCSV
    }

    Catch
    {
        DisplayMSGBox -MSGText "Could not access CSV file." -AddErrorInfo $True | Out-Null

        LogFileCleanUp

        [System.Environment]::Exit(0)
    }

    ShowWallBoard

    #---Form
    $Form                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.Size            = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(184,197)
    $Form.Font            = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI",9,0,3,1)
    $Form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedSingle"    
    $Form.MaximizeBox     = $False
    $Form.Text            = "S/R Visitor Badge"
    $Form.StartPosition   = "CenterScreen"

    #---GroupBox Badges
    $GBBadges          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
    $GBBadges.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,5)
    $GBBadges.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(158,70)
    $GBBadges.Text     = "Badge"

    #Badge choice
    $CBBadgeChoice               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $CBBadgeChoice.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20)
    $CBBadgeChoice.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110)
    $CBBadgeChoice.FlatStyle     = "PopUp"
    $CBBadgeChoice.DropDownStyle = 2

    #---Retrieving badge list
    Try
    {
        ForEach($Badge in $BadgeList)
        {
            $CBBadgeChoice.Items.Add("Visitor Badge $BadgeIndex") | Out-Null

            $BadgeIndex++
        }
    }

    Catch
    {
        DisplayMSGBox -MSGText "Could generate badge choice combobox." -AddErrorInfo $True | Out-Null

        LogFileCleanUp

        [System.Environment]::Exit(0)
    }

    $CBBadgeChoice.SelectedIndex = 0

    #Unlink
    $ChBUnlink           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    $ChBUnlink.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,47)
    $ChBUnlink.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(135,18)
    $ChBUnlink.FlatStyle = "Flat"
    $ChBUnlink.Text      = "Unlink this badge"

    #PictureBox Badge
    $PBBadge          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    $PBBadge.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,23)
    $PBBadge.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(16,16)   
    $PBBadge.Image    = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$ScriptPath\images\cross.PNG")

    #---GroupBox User
    $GBUser          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
    $GBUser.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,77)
    $GBUser.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(158,53)
    $GBUser.Text     = "User"

    #UserName
    $TBUserName             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $TBUserName.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20)
    $TBUserName.Size        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110)
    $TBUserName.BorderStyle = 1

    #PictureBox UserName
    $PBUserName           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    $PBUserName.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,23)
    $PBUserName.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(16,16)   
    $PBUserName.Image     = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$ScriptPath\images\cross.PNG")

    #---Buttons
    $BValidate           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $BValidate.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,139)
    $BValidate.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $BValidate.FlatStyle = "PopUp"
    $BValidate.Text      = "Validate"

    $BConfirm           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $BConfirm.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(93,139)
    $BConfirm.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $BConfirm.FlatStyle = "PopUp"
    $BConfirm.Text      = "Confirm"
    $BConfirm.Enabled   = $False

    #---Eventhandling
    $DisableTextBox=
    {
        #---"Unlink this badge" is unchecked
        if($ChBUnlink.Checked -eq $False)
        {
            #---Enable texbox
            $TBUserName.Enabled = $True

            #---Clear textbox
            $TBUserName.Text = ""

            #---Set both picture boxes to cross.png
            $PBBadge.Image = $PBUserName.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$ScriptPath\images\cross.PNG")
        }

        #---"Unlink this badge" is checked
        if($ChBUnlink.Checked -eq $True)
        {
            #---Disable textbox
            $TBUserName.Enabled = $False

            #---Clear textbox
            $TBUserName.Text = ""

            #---Set the picture box next to the username input textbox to tick.png
            $PBUserName.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$ScriptPath\images\tick.PNG")

            #---Setting badge check
            $BadgeChk = $False

            #---Set the picture box next to badge choice combobox to tick.png
            $PBBadge.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$ScriptPath\images\cross.PNG")
        }
    }

    #---Buttons On-Click-Actions
    $BValidate_OnClick= 
    {   
        #---Param
        [String]$UserName = $TBUserName.Text             # -> Username

        [Int]$BadgeCSVID  = $CBBadgeChoice.SelectedIndex # -> Index which indicates which badge got selected: Index = 0 -> Visitor Badge 1, Index 1 -> Visitor Badge 2

        [Long]$BadgeID    = $BadgeList[$BadgeCSVID].ID   # -> Getting badge id from csv file 

        $Form.Enabled = $False

        Try
        {
            #---UserChk
            if($UserName -ne "")
            {
                $UserChk = Invoke-Command -Session $OurADServer -ScriptBlock{Param($UserName) [Bool](Get-ADUser -Filter { sAMAccountName -eq $UserName } -Searchbase "SB")} -ArgumentList $UserName

                if($UserChk -eq $False)
                {
                    $PBUserName.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$ScriptPath\images\cross.PNG")
                }

                ElseIf($UserChk -eq $True)
                {
                    $PBUserName.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$ScriptPath\images\tick.PNG")
                }
            }
        }

        Catch
        {
            DisplayMSGBox -MSGText "Could not validate the user." -AddErrorInfo $True | Out-Null

            LogFileCleanUp

            [System.Environment]::Exit(0)
        }

        Try
        {
            #---BadgeChk
            $BadgeChk = Invoke-Command -Session $OurADServer -ScriptBlock{Param($BadgeID) [Bool](Get-ADObject -Filter { Pager -eq $BadgeID })} -ArgumentList $BadgeID

            if($BadgeChk -eq $True)
            {   
                #---Retrieving all linked ad objects
                $AllLinkedObjectsArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

                $AllLinkedObjects = Invoke-Command -Session $OurADServer -ScriptBlock{Param($BadgeID) Get-ADObject -Filter { Pager -eq $BadgeID }} -ArgumentList $BadgeID

                ForEach($Object in $AllLinkedObjects)
                {
                    $AllLinkedObjectsArray.Add($Object.Name) | Out-Null
                }

                #---Joins array into string with breaks
                $AllLinkedObjectsString = $AllLinkedObjectsArray -Join "
    "

                if($ChBUnlink.Checked -eq $False)
                {
                    $PBBadge.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$ScriptPath\images\cross.PNG")

                    if((DisplayMSGBox -MSGText ($CBBadgeChoice.SelectedItem + " is already linked with the following objects:`n`n$AllLinkedObjectsString`n`nDo you wish to clear these links?”) -MSGButtons YesNo -MSGIcon Question) -eq "Yes")
                    {
                        ReleaseVisitorBadge $AllLinkedObjectsString $BadgeCSVID $BadgeID
                    }
                }

                elseif($ChBUnlink.Checked -eq $True)
                {
                    $PBBadge.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$ScriptPath\images\tick.PNG")
                }
            }

            elseif($BadgeChk -eq $False)
            {
                if($ChBUnlink.Checked -eq $False)
                {
                    $PBBadge.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$ScriptPath\images\tick.PNG")
                }

                elseif($ChBUnlink.Checked -eq $True)
                {
                    $PBBadge.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$ScriptPath\images\cross.PNG")

                    DisplayMSGBox -MSGText ($CBBadgeChoice.SelectedItem + " is currently not in use.") -MSGIcon Information | Out-Null
                }
            }
        }

        Catch
        {
            DisplayMSGBox -MSGText "Could not validate the badge." -AddErrorInfo $True | Out-Null

            LogFileCleanUp

            [System.Environment]::Exit(0)
        }

        $Form.Enabled = $True

        #---Enabling / disabling the button "Confirm"
        if(($BadgeChk -eq $False -and $UserChk -eq $True) -or ($BadgeChk -eq $True -and $ChBUnlink.Checked -eq $True))
        {
            $BConfirm.Enabled = $True
        }

        else
        {
            $BConfirm.Enabled = $False
        }
    }

    $BConfirm_OnClick= 
    {
        if($BadgeChk -eq $False -and $UserChk -eq $True)
        {
            Set-Variable -Name Exit -Value $False -Scope Global

            $Form.Close()

            SetVisitorBadge $UserName $BadgeCSVID $BadgeID
        }

        ElseIf($BadgeChk -eq $True -and $ChBUnlink.Checked -eq $True)
        {
            Set-Variable -Name Exit -Value $False -Scope Global

            $Form.Close()

            ReleaseVisitorBadge $AllLinkedObjectsString $BadgeCSVID $BadgeID
        }
    }

    #---Adding Elements to the form
    $BValidate.Add_Click($BValidate_OnClick)
    $BConfirm.Add_Click($BConfirm_OnClick)

    $ChBUnlink.Add_CheckedChanged($DisableTextBox)

    $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate(); $TBUserName.Focus()})

    $GBBadges.Controls.Add($CBBadgeChoice)
    $GBBadges.Controls.Add($PBBadge)
    $GBBadges.Controls.Add($ChBUnlink)  

    $GBUser.Controls.Add($TBUserName)
    $GBUser.Controls.Add($PBUserName)

    $Form.Controls.Add($GBBadges)
    $Form.Controls.Add($GBUser)

    $Form.Controls.Add($BValidate)
    $Form.Controls.Add($BConfirm)

    $Form.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
}
```

I have two options in my userform. After the user has entered the data, he has to validate it by clicking on "Validate". If everything is correct, the button "Confirm" gets activated and the AD user object may be changed.

However, after validating the data and then clicking on "Confirm" all necessary variables lost their values and I don't know why.

As you can see below, everything is set after validating the data but when I try to confirm it, all values are gone.

[image]

The script worked just fine as it is now when run directly on our AD server. All I did was trying to run it via my system by adding a remote session and `Invoke-Command`'s. Could this really be an issue here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try adding the variable to the parent scope. You can do so using Set-Variable and setting the scope to 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now. Do you have any idea why this is now necessary but is not needed when the script runs directly on the server?